# Find maxPeakElement in an array in Java

Tags: java

I was asked to find the maximum index of a peak element in an array, but I have to take in count the left element and right element, and if there´s no peak, I should return -1, currently I have this solution:

```
public int maxPeakIndex(int[] n) {
       

        int n = paymentDelays.length;
        int maxPeakIndex = -1;
        int maxPeakValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> peakIndices = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int p = n[i];
            if ((i == 0 || p > n[i - 1]) &&
                    (i == n - 1 || p > n[i + 1])) {
                if (p > maxPeakValue) {
                    maxPeakValue = p;
                    maxPeakIndex = i;
                    peakIndices.put(maxPeakValue, maxPeakIndex);
                } else if (p == maxPeakValue) {
                    peakIndices.put(maxPeakValue, i);
                }
            }
        }

        return maxPeakIndex;

    }
```

Everything is working fine except following test which is failling:

```
@Test
    public void maxPeakTest5() {
        Risk risk = new Risk();
        int index = risk.maxPeakIndex(new int[]{17, 18, 17, 1, 0, 16, 0, 0});
        Assertions.assertEquals(5, index);
    }
```

I'm getting 1, since my code is identifying 18 as the highest peak, but I was asked to keep in count the highest difference, in this specific scenario, it should be 5 since from 0 it went to 16 and then it went down to 0 again, so that's like a high change and that should be considered as the highest peak, but i'm not able to make it work, any ideas ? thank you

These tests are passing well:

```
(new int[]{3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 3});
        Assertions.assertEquals(7, index);

new int[]{0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0});
        Assertions.assertEquals(-1, index);


(new int[]{5, 4, 2, 2, 0, 10, 8, 3});
        Assertions.assertEquals(5, index);

(new int[]{5, 4, 2, 2, 0, 10, 10, 3});
        Assertions.assertEquals(0, index);
```

Comment: I have my own idea what constitutes a peak.  What is yours?  Since `18` goes to `17`  goes to `1`, from one side, that could be the highest.   Would something like `10, 16, 1` be a peak of height `15`?

Answer (score 0):

You are not keeping track of the difference, hence the wrong value.

Try this...

```
public static int maxPeakIndex(int[] paymentDelays) {
    int n = paymentDelays.length;
    int maxPeakIndex = -1;
    int maxDiff = 0;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> peakIndices = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int p = paymentDelays[i];

        if (i == 0) continue;
        if (paymentDelays[i] - paymentDelays[i - 1] > maxDiff) {
            maxDiff = paymentDelays[i] - paymentDelays[i - 1];
            maxPeakIndex = i;
            peakIndices.put(p, i);
        }
    }

    return maxPeakIndex;
}
```